# Cloud NDB: transactionally put() multiple entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb

There are situations where we must save two or more datastore entities at once (either both entities are saved or neither is saved). For my example, I want to create a UserProfile entity when a User entity is created.

from entities import User, UserProfile

```
def create_user_and_profile():
    # First, create the User entity
    user = User(email=email, password=password_hash)
    user.put()

    # Then, create a UserProfile entity
    # that takes a user.key as parent
    user_profile = UserProfile(parent=user.key)
    user_profile.put()
```

The function above is not atomic. It is possible that only one or neither of the entities are saved successfully.

How can I make this atomic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's `transactional` decorator in `ndb` you can use. If any of the records would fail to be saved, none of them will:

```
from google.cloud import ndb


@ndb.transactional()
def create_user_and_profile():
    # First, create the User entity
    user = User(email=email, password=password_hash)
    user.put()

    # Then, create a UserProfile entity
    # that takes a user.key as parent
    user_profile = UserProfile(parent=user.key)
    user_profile.put()

with ndb_client.context(): # ndb client instance
    create_user_and_profile()
```